# is_main_query not working with ( pre_get_posts ) hook

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

When I use is_main_query my function not working. When I remove this from condition function works find.

```
I tried with this code
function education_adjust_query($query){
    if(!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('event') && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query -> set('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'education_adjust_query');
```

Here I set 1 item should show in the custom post type archive page. When I use $query->is_main_query() it showing default number of items. When remove this function works find.

Comment: _"in the custom post type archive page"_ - so that is _not_ the main query then. You should look into https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_post_type_archive/